# Is there a REST User Interface for Flask?

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I've seen that Django provides a makeshift interface for testing REST API's, like **in this image**:

[image: Image taken from google]

I was thinking of making some crude page using raw html and python class dicts, but I think it will be ugly and there may be something already at hand.

So, **is there anything similar to Django REST interface for Flask** (especially for flask restful?)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, but not natively.

There's a module called Flasgger, that implements the Swagger interface and OpenAPI documentation in Flask and is really a big help!

Read more in the Github page: https://github.com/flasgger/flasgger

Here's a Picture of the interface:

[image: Flasgger interface]